# Sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error() returns negative number

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to understand why `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error()` returning a **negative number**?
I know it is not possible but this is what is happening on my machine, actually 2 machines. I am using Python 3.6 and sklearn(0.0).

The code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
predictions = [96271]
test = [35241]
mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('MSE: %.3f' % mse)

Ouput: MSE: -570306396.000
```

Here is the screenshot of debugger showing the negative value:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcO2U.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce; getting `MSE: 3724660900.000`, as @StupidWolf in their answer below. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new code the issue seems to just be an int overflow

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
>>> predictions = [96271]
>>> test = [35241]
>>> mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
-570306396.0
>>> np.float32(96271 - 35241)**2
3724660900
>>> np.int32(96271 - 35241)**2
-570306396
```

The natural question is when does it break, since built-in python int would not overflow

```
>>> (96271 - 35241)**2
3724660900
```

So the problem arises when scikit learn wraps your data into numpy array in

```
    y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
        y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
```

which identifies your data type as int32, and outputs np.array(..., dtype=np.int32), which then overflows.

Note that simply making sure things look like floats will work too

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
>>> predictions = [96271.] # Note the dot!
>>> test = [35241.]
>>> mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
3724660900
```

Comment: Yes that worked ! Thanks. Being new to Python and ML this behavior is surprising, is this documented somewhere or it is just how Python is ?

Comment: This is how fixed precision arithmetics on integers work. Python built-in integer is flexible size, so will not fail in such a way, but numpy is essentially a chunk of c++ code, which is more.. strict and easy to break. You can read more about numpy types and overflows here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html?highlight=s#overflow-errors

Answer (score 1):

The only way MSE can be negative is if you provided `sample_weights` (or `multioutput`) that is negative. e.g.

```
mean_squared_error([0, 0], [1, 0], sample_weight=[-1, 1.2])
-5.000000000000001
```

since what sklearn does is it first takes square of differences, and then takes a weighted average using

```
avg = sum(a * weights) / sum(weights)
```

which can be negative if some weight is negative, but sum is positive.

From the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L274):

```py
    y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
        y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    output_errors = np.average((y_true - y_pred) ** 2, axis=0,
                               weights=sample_weight)

    if not squared:
        output_errors = np.sqrt(output_errors)

    if isinstance(multioutput, str):
        if multioutput == 'raw_values':
            return output_errors
        elif multioutput == 'uniform_average':
            # pass None as weights to np.average: uniform mean
            multioutput = None

    return np.average(output_errors, weights=multioutput)
```

Specifically note the

```
output_errors = np.average((y_true - y_pred) ** 2, axis=0,
                               weights=sample_weight)
```

line, which shows where the negative output can come from.

There is a thread discussing questionable choice of numpy authors to accept negative weights in averaging https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9825, but as it stands now in 2021, the average still does accept these weights, and acts in a way that might surprise people.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I did not provide sample_weights (or multioutput), just a couple of lists of positive numbers. Spent some time trying to figure it out but could not, currently using mean_absolute_error.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, as this really does not seem possible from the code. Scikit learn team would also benefit from a bug report if this is indeed happening.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error, I am on Python 3.8.5, sklearn 0.24.1, numpy 1.20.1 I get:

```
mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('MSE: %.3f' % mse)
MSE: 3724660900.000
```

Looking at the numbers, my guess is that they are defaulted to np.int32 in the calculation, so the square of your values exceed 2,147,483,647. You can try:

```
mean_squared_error(np.float64(test),np.float64(predictions))
```

Might be good to check your version of numpy / scikit-learn

Comment: Cannot reproduce either; voting to close as such.